# css styling issues - image doesn't scroll down while text does

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have an image on the left side of my screen and I want the text to flow down on the right of the screen by the image. This is kinda already what I have, but the text only allows scroll down when the mouse is hovering over the paragraph and not just on the page or window, which seems to be confusing people that are using this site. If that doesn't make sense I'd be happy to take a short video to show what I mean. Anyone know how to solve this? I want the image to remain on the screen AT ALL TIMES and the text to scroll down, but be able to do this by scrolling down anywhere on the page (not just the text itself).

```
p {
    word-break: break-word;  
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    padding-left: 90px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%); 
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: #91adc2;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100px;
}


  div {
      background-color: #91adc2 !important;
  }
```

```
<div class='nav'>
  <div>
  <img src='../../assets/img/face.png' alt="wj" /></div>
  <p>Welcome to my portfolio! 
  
 LONG PARAGRAPH HERE 
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue and what you want. I created a Codepen here. Please check it and let me know whats the desired behaviour? https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/abZdgvR

Comment: This makes it sound like it should not be in a fixed position. If it should scroll with the text, just remove the height constraint on the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
    word-break: break-word;  
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
/*     overflow: auto; */
  
/*  set this to clear the image  */
    padding-left: 200px;
}

img {
    padding-left: 90px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, white 100%); 
   
    /* fixed position at all times */
    position:fixed;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: #91adc2;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    
    /* height: 100vh; */
    padding-top: 100px;
}




  div {
      background-color: #91adc2 !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class='nav'>
  <div>
<!--   <img src='../../assets/img/face.png' alt="wj" /> -->
  <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png' alt="wj" width="100" class="avatar"/></div>
  <p>Welcome to my portfolio! 
  
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dolor tortor, mattis et venenatis et, fringilla eu sapien. Ut blandit maximus sapien, et pellentesque elit ullamcorper in. Sed mattis eros in quam posuere pharetra. Etiam aliquet mattis purus, et luctus ligula. Proin bibendum lectus sed lorem vestibulum vestibulum. Donec accumsan erat ex. Maecenas in tempor metus. Duis venenatis elit magna, sed tristique nisi sodales eget. Maecenas dignissim nisl massa, accumsan vehicula turpis elementum sit amet. Fusce mollis mi eget est egestas, nec luctus tellus mollis. Suspendisse vitae nulla semper, elementum lacus eget, sodales lectus. Quisque iaculis ipsum elementum, efficitur ex sit amet, efficitur erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed imperdiet convallis urna id commodo.

Pellentesque erat nunc, congue in mattis sed, rutrum et felis. Etiam gravida fringilla mattis. Quisque vestibulum diam ex, tincidunt mattis metus efficitur eu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nulla facilisi. Aenean mattis sapien est, in vulputate metus accumsan at. Phasellus maximus sit amet nisl id tincidunt.

Sed venenatis consectetur ex in blandit. Nam vestibulum convallis scelerisque. Vivamus eleifend nibh tortor, sit amet sollicitudin velit luctus quis. In eu justo sed lorem elementum elementum. Integer pellentesque augue ex, sit amet congue nibh eleifend eu. Vivamus ultrices purus in orci placerat, ornare efficitur elit fringilla. Nunc pretium, est sit amet tempor sodales, nibh nibh fermentum ipsum, in cursus felis neque ac odio. Mauris sit amet suscipit mi, eu gravida nibh. Pellentesque quis ornare enim, a tempus nisi. Nulla posuere odio molestie metus scelerisque, eget molestie augue efficitur. Integer eleifend metus quis urna tincidunt fringilla. Morbi nec neque sit amet ex hendrerit rutrum. Proin tellus magna, accumsan at purus quis, cursus commodo nibh.

Pellentesque pretium, massa eu pellentesque sollicitudin, sem neque ultricies leo, aliquet eleifend quam ipsum a tellus. Proin dictum mauris nunc, quis iaculis libero pharetra sit amet. Nam rhoncus porttitor ante maximus sollicitudin. In libero nisl, suscipit pretium velit ac, malesuada laoreet ex. Suspendisse sit amet enim mauris. Nulla ornare ex lectus, eu malesuada eros luctus vitae. Vivamus purus augue, ultricies at tristique ut, porttitor non tellus. Cras congue erat vitae condimentum volutpat. Quisque id leo posuere, tempus justo vel, egestas sapien. Proin ultrices turpis nec dui volutpat ultricies. Vivamus iaculis urna vel placerat tincidunt.

Quisque fringilla erat eu tellus elementum, at aliquet magna scelerisque. Sed ac felis semper, congue mi id, condimentum purus. Nulla scelerisque at nunc dapibus semper. Maecenas eget purus non quam tempor porttitor nec vitae diam. Suspendisse vel ligula ut justo hendrerit pharetra. Fusce nec lacus dignissim, molestie ligula ut, pharetra sapien. Donec eu velit ex. Nullam eu orci ut tortor condimentum dapibus nec at ante. 
    </p>
</div>
```

I would set the img to be `position: fixed;` then adjust the `padding-left` on the text.

Comment: yes thanks this is what I was looking for! sorry if there was some confusion with what I was asking. The only issue I have now is that the image seems to stick to the bottom of the page and padding/margins don't do anything, any ideas on that?

Comment: you can set the left and top position of the img according to your needs. `left:90px; top:90px;` for example.